# How to merge columns from different tables on python

Tags: python, pandas

My input:

- user_feature table each row presents user's information
- coupon_feature table each row presents details of each coupon
- coupon_detail_train each row presents which user purchase which
  coupon

expect output:

- columns represents all user_feature table and coupon_feature table
  combined by using 'USER_ID_hash' and 'COUPON_ID_hash' on
- coupon_detail_train table row represents which user purchases which coupon

Problem:

For the result, I got zero row. Not the output I expect.

[columns wanted to merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78U85.png)

```
user_feature = user_list.loc[:, ['SEX_ID', 'AGE', 'PREF_NAME','USER_ID_hash']]
coupon_feature = coupon_list_test.loc[:, ['PRICE_RATE', 'CATALOG_PRICE',
       'DISCOUNT_PRICE', 'DISPFROM', 'DISPEND', 'DISPPERIOD', 'VALIDFROM',
       'VALIDEND', 'VALIDPERIOD', 'USABLE_DATE_MON', 'USABLE_DATE_TUE',
       'USABLE_DATE_WED', 'USABLE_DATE_THU', 'USABLE_DATE_FRI',
       'USABLE_DATE_SAT', 'USABLE_DATE_SUN', 'USABLE_DATE_HOLIDAY',
       'USABLE_DATE_BEFORE_HOLIDAY', 'COUPON_ID_hash']]
coupon_detail_train.columns
x = user_feature.merge(coupon_detail_train, on = 'USER_ID_hash')
x = coupon_feature.merge(x, on = 'COUPON_ID_hash')
```

Comment: I assume you're using Pandas, so I added the [tag:pandas] tag for you. If that's incorrect, you can [edit] to fix it. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made typo coupon_list_test, it should be coupon_list_train instead.

```
coupon_feature = coupon_list_train.loc[:, ['PRICE_RATE', 'CATALOG_PRICE',
       'DISCOUNT_PRICE', 'DISPFROM', 'DISPEND', 'DISPPERIOD', 'VALIDFROM',
       'VALIDEND', 'VALIDPERIOD', 'USABLE_DATE_MON', 'USABLE_DATE_TUE',
       'USABLE_DATE_WED', 'USABLE_DATE_THU', 'USABLE_DATE_FRI',
       'USABLE_DATE_SAT', 'USABLE_DATE_SUN', 'USABLE_DATE_HOLIDAY',
       'USABLE_DATE_BEFORE_HOLIDAY', 'COUPON_ID_hash']]
```